# Get output from the search with PHP

Tags: php, forms, data-extraction

I would like to get the output of my search from "https://login.ku.edu.tr/eGuide/servlet/eGuide" which is my university's eguide. However it is only accessible with in campus or the vpn.

My aim is, writing the php code which gets the output of the field "Location" in any search. But it is also ok if the code only works in the in campus or the computers who are login in the vpn servers.

How can I get this value from the search ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

that depends entirely on the format of the content retrieved by that search. without seeing any code, or resultant HTML, we can't provide any real advice for extracting the data. basically, you probably want to do some research on page scraping.

Comment: I tried to do get info, I found a very long link that has the username in it, and when I call this url with curl in php, it does return only a blank page =/